# Expanding my program

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, user-input, favorites

So i got a programm that asks the user to type in the 3 favorite cities ,
it stores them in Array and prints them later out to the user. What im trying to do now is
making the programm ask the user for how many favorite cities he/she got?the user types in
a number wich will give the user the oppertunity to type in that ammount of favorit cities
and later on print them out.

Problem is i really have no idea how to do this could anyone help?

Please explain the code incase you help so i can understand :) , Sorry for my bad English not my 
primary language!

My code atm looks like this :

```
package com.example.array.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] favoritCity = new String [3];
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("skriv in 3 favoritstäder");
        String userIn1 = scanner1.nextLine();
        String userIn2 = scanner1.nextLine();
        String userIn3 = scanner1.nextLine();


        favoritCity[0] = userIn1;
        favoritCity[1] = userIn2;
        favoritCity[2] = userIn3;


        System.out.println(userIn1);
        System.out.println(userIn2);
        System.out.println(userIn3);

            }

    }
```

Comment: Hint - take a look at java loops (for/while)

Comment: yea im looking at tutorials atm but really havent solved it yet

Comment: If you want us to write your code, we can (although SO is not the place for it). If you want to learn java - you need to try do it yourself. If you have specific questions we can help. My hint should help you.

Comment: you're right but problem is mostly i only need to change a piece of the code but cant find it like yesterday my fizzbuzz failed cuz i had syste.out.print instead of println i didnt see it but somone else saw it instantly , and usually whenever i get help by somone Writing in a code to help i usually research around it many times so i understand it to use it in the future not just type it in.

Answer (score 0):

Before to define your Array size, you can use your scanner to ask for the number of cities, for example:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many cities?");
    int nberCities = scanner.nextInt();

    String[] favoriteCities = new String[nberCities];
    for(int i = 0; i < nberCities;i++){
      favoriteCities[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for that idea barbe that really helps out !

Answer (score 0):

First take a integer input from user, that how many favorite cities does he/she have? 
`Scanner#nextInt();` which could help you get integer input from console. Create a array with that size Then write loop like -

```
String[] favoritCity = new String [noOfFabCities];
for(int i=0;i<maxFavCities;i++){
    ...
}
```

Now inside the loop get the input from user Enter your `i+1` (as i starts with 0) favorite city and capture the input like `Scanner#nextLine();`. and keep the value into your array like -

```
favoritCity[i] = userInput;
```

Once you get all the user input, now can you print in console all the user's favorite cities.

Answer (score 0):

That should be the code which are you looking for. I don't tested it, but it should works.

```
package com.example.array.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int cityNumb;

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("How many favorite cities do you have?");
        cityNumb = scanner1.nextInt();

        //creat the array with the size of cityNumb
        String[] favoritCity = new String [cityNumb];

        System.out.println("skriv in "+cityNumb+" favoritstäder");

        //for loop for the input of the cities
        for(int i = 0; i < cityNumb; i++) 
        { 
            String city = scanner1.nextLine();
            favoritCity[i] = city;
        }

        //for loop for the output of the cities
        for(int i = 0; i < cityNumb; i++) 
        { 
            System.out.println(favoritCity[i]);
        }

    }

}
```